# How to correctly determine the return type of a function depending on the value in the argument (TypeScript)?

Tags: typescript

There is a case when the return type is already known to me when passing a parameter to a function, but I have difficulty trying to explain this to TypeScript.

```
export enum DatePreset {
  Today = "Today",
  ThisMonth = "This month",
  ThisYear = "This year",
  Custom = "Custom"
}

export interface DateRange {
  from: Date;
  to?: Date;
}

export interface DateRangeWithPreset extends DateRange {
  preset: DatePreset;
}

export function applyPreset<T extends DatePreset = DatePreset>(
  preset: T
): T extends DatePreset.Custom ? undefined : Required<DateRangeWithPreset> {
  const presets: Record<
    Exclude<DatePreset, DatePreset.Custom>,
    Required<DateRange>
  > = {
    [DatePreset.Today]: { from: new Date(), to: new Date() },
    [DatePreset.ThisMonth]: { from: new Date(), to: new Date() },
    [DatePreset.ThisYear]: { from: new Date(), to: new Date() }
  };

  // Delete these comments and try to help me solve this problems with types.

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-ignore
  // readyPreset: any
  const readyPreset = presets[preset];

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-ignore
  return readyPreset && { preset, ...readyPreset };
}

// Right behaviors:

// const validUndefinedRange: undefined
const validUndefinedRange = applyPreset(DatePreset.Custom);

// const thisYearRange: Required<DateRangeWithPreset>
const thisYearRange = applyPreset(DatePreset.ThisYear);

console.log("validUndefinedRange", validUndefinedRange);
console.log("thisYearRange", thisYearRange);
```

There is a function that returns an object with values from, to and preset. Which range is returned depends on the parameter.
In my case, the DatePreset.Custom parameter will always return undefined, and the rest - an object.
I found a working solution, but Eslint and TS don't like it. Please help me type the function correctly.

[Here CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-booth-8fwx0h?file=/src/index.ts).

Comment: Does this question actually depend on `date-fns`?  If so then please tag it as such.  If not, then please consider removing it from the code here so it will be a [mre].

Comment: In fact, it does not depend, removed it so as not to load with unnecessary imports.

Comment: Is it more important that the compiler follow your logic and verify its type safety?  Or is it more important that your emitted JS code stay as-is but the compiler doesn't complain about it?  You can't really have both.  If you don't mind refactoring to satisfy the compiler then you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0A8OW).  Otherwise you will run into the issue in [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) and you need to work around it with something like a type assertion, perhaps like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wERk2N).  Which, if either, would you prefer?

Comment: Type safety checking is my priority. Both options are interesting and work great. But I stopped at your first solution, but removed the getters. I try not to use unsafe type casting, as in the second example.
Here's what happened in the end: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-torvalds-v93o02?file=/src/index.ts

Thank you very much!

Comment: So should I write up an answer with the first solution?  Note that the advantage of getters is that you only compute the value you want to return; in your version you are computing `withPreset(...)` for everything and then throwing most of what you've computed away.  But this difference is probably out of scope for the question as asked.

Comment: Yes, you can write the first option. I know the coolness of getters and I totally agree with you, but they are better used with a standard higher than ES5, which is what the compiler will warn about, so I removed them because I'm not sure what standard my command will use. And will definitely come back to your solution if it's higher than ES5.

Comment: All right I will do so when I get a chance; it might be a while because I am traveling right now

Comment: Still hoping to get to this soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your function as-is, returning a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter, then it really isn't possible to have the compiler verify type safety.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for the feature request to allow some way for the compiler to verify safety of such functions.  For now there's no support for this.  So  you'd have to take the burden of type safety verification upon yourself and just tell the compiler not to worry about it.

I wouldn't ever recommend that you use [the `// @ts-ignore` directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) except as a last resort.  That's basically just suppressing and not fixing the error.  Instead you could use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) like this:

```
export function applyPresetAssert<T extends DatePreset = DatePreset>(
  preset: T
) {
  const presets: Record<
    Exclude<DatePreset, DatePreset.Custom>,
    Required<DateRange>
  > & { [DatePreset.Custom]?: undefined } = { 
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  // tell the compiler about this property being undefined
    [DatePreset.Today]: { from: new Date(), to: new Date() },
    [DatePreset.ThisMonth]: { from: new Date(), to: new Date() },
    [DatePreset.ThisYear]: { from: new Date(), to: new Date() }
  };

  const readyPreset = presets[preset]; // okay

  return (readyPreset && { preset, ...readyPreset }) as 
  (undefined | Required<DateRangeWithPreset>) as 
  (T extends DatePreset.Custom ? undefined : Required<DateRangeWithPreset>);
}
```

That sequence of `as` expressions at the end is the assertion you need to do to suppress the error in a compiler-friendly way.  You're telling the compiler that the resulting value can be considered of that union type, which can then be considered of the conditional type.

If you make a mistake in your implementation the compiler will probably not catch it, so you have to be careful.

---

But you said you care more about compiler-verified type safety than keeping your function as-is.  So you can refactor to get behavior the compiler understands.  Generic conditional types have to be abandoned.  Instead you can get similar behavior by indexing into an object with a generic key; if you have a value `obj` of type `Obj`, and a key `k` of generic type `K`, then the compiler will understand that `obj[k]` has [the indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `Obj[K]`.

So let's refactor so that you're performing a single object lookup:

```
export function applyPreset<T extends DatePreset = DatePreset>(
  preset: T
) {
  const wrap = <T extends object>(x: T) => ({ preset, ...x });
  const presets:
    { [K in DatePreset]:
      K extends DatePreset.Custom ? undefined : Required<DateRangeWithPreset>
    } = {
    get [DatePreset.Today]() { return wrap({ from: new Date(), to: new Date() }) },
    get [DatePreset.ThisMonth]() { return wrap({ from: new Date(), to: new Date() }) },
    get [DatePreset.ThisYear]() { return wrap({ from: new Date(), to: new Date() }) },
    [DatePreset.Custom]: undefined
  };
  return presets[preset];
}
```

So the `presets` object is no longer a static thing, but is created on the fly as a function of the `preset` parameter.  I used [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) so that only the property actually accessed will cause the code to be run, but you don't have to do this.  The compiler can verify that the type of `presets` matches its [annotated type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables): for all `DatePreset` keys except `Custom`, the property value is of type `Required<DateRangeWithPreset>`, and otherwise it is `undefined`.

And then we just return `presets[preset]`, which the compiler sees as being of type

```
{
    Today: Required<DateRangeWithPreset>;
    "This month": Required<DateRangeWithPreset>;
    "This year": Required<DateRangeWithPreset>;
    Custom: undefined;
}[T]
```

Let's test it out:

```
const validUndefinedRange = applyPreset(DatePreset.Custom);
// const validUndefinedRange: undefined
console.log("validUndefinedRange", validUndefinedRange);
// "validUndefinedRange",  undefined 

const thisYearRange = applyPreset(DatePreset.ThisYear);
// const thisYearRange: Required<DateRangeWithPreset>
console.log("thisYearRange", thisYearRange);
/* "thisYearRange",  {
  "preset": "This year",
  "from": "2022-10-01T16:25:21.296Z",
  "to": "2022-10-01T16:25:21.296Z"
*/
```

Looks good. When you call the function, the compiler still gives the right types and the implementation still gives the right values.  And you don't have to suppress any compiler errors.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIghgF2ABQE7AM7AVA3gKCigBUB7AEzgE8oBeKAIjMqoYBpCSALASwwFlSIBFzqNivDFAhCR7ThL4BNYHFRimkqFVWp5RAMJgMCUtHoMjJsw3wBffPh7DgqAGZwAxsFiJgAJTgQAHMfAiI3VDMALl8kAG5OUwB+WPgE+0dnJHcvH3SAoNCAdR4RNExsKGAADyQQcikCwJCwzgAHdCwENL8K7sSHfDcwEE8EHiEoOHb2gBsqfuwAQQwsVAQAHmJqutBGuJQuqvoCpYQAPgAKDuOeknwASjxOTyETKE7KhAxY-2A3qhyJtOEQAKI1TxzMDkYCbM53NiHc4AOispggFw4RCI-wAjmAeOhgc0isALpwLlAAGR4KAAbQR3zRxgxAF1UlBRrC3M5gOQoHYxOEcYy+ncUcxqGzYrgoJEYlAQMAAO6HK6PJGmWLKtUFDWC7GipndSWSQTCLgyukKiA61XqzVQbVKh36552I1EMVIVGKDAqNTWuW2+16vwarWkMOOwWcOyJV7vHDoODkRZ3MRfboYenZ7BsxNEdAIMCoEBQK6p9PnGm0uX5hBIlEt6sZ76C55wDCgyvc4C85UCgA+UHxhOJ8L8LRKZS45wuXZ7OMrO1q9QOJuwLOs0GSXIaA75Ar+wAJRP5U6QM+ApXKd0Xg0cIzGEymM3m7e6212G6a4o7U4AO6a5bm+WJiCeF4iDeEAPhVVAZjEH9132KRSAAIwAKwBS4rhqCDnloKkrgbREoBbFEak7RIYOTT47l+Xs5XpABpKBnGRO4ZV7Ih2NQhp-19CV0TMKB937Qd+SgU9z0nUlWjvecH17IV6BFIhQhwH0jmZKUqDZA05RLMsKwQmZSPlKI7VdcMkEjZ1o1s2M7A9L0oC0hktwQM0+AtERDOeYzsFMqBzPaSzQ2c90oxjd1O0NXtPJ0v1JEDVBArpEzyzCxCIpDay4ojJ0XV1Fy3N7FKRNZMxrUk4941oqBsorRtc0bQtMgAegAKnlUZxkmCsPwWc4UL2QSuMAqaQKuRtCNlXt9NkidLwU2d72+C4mqITQ+GkWQuAYFaLxJacySUhcdvELQdDUY6xzPVbgUo7be1Emz6qHQZ6WINkoB6rrHHwWCPgANzgOYeHIABVQ8pPIG8xBGr9sCubydwxR5Ei6rqoFBnAIah2H4ePG9Yi+-kQfeUg5mAFE5lIYIrgYInobhnkybJdgoDZknOaHG9sfwXHGD5jmj0F7mkQPAXpMcAnnTS3QkfoFHznR4Dt39dLhdFxWRGUFWyRO+TzsUucF2puDafpxnmYYQ2A2N1oead9KhZxvrHeVtQbx56DGEbB69qkO69CNBhbRDgAmAAGGOY4AWgARjjpO45T4gU4ANmiGOAFZ85TlEY4AThzgAtfRGFMWOE+TtOM6z3P86LmOS-LqvbEB-AgA)